# Changing the location of a vmdk virtualbox ubuntu 16.04

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to move a vmdk of my boxes to another directory (memory reasons) without having to reinstall the vm-s.After trying to add a SAS controler (after removing the old one) i get this:

```
Cannot register the hard disk '/path/to/new.vmdk' 
{5db8bd55-a363-4730-8677-7561e3a44127} 
because a hard disk '/path/to/old.vmdk' with UUID 
{5db8bd55-a363-4730-8677-7561e3a44127} 
already exists.
```

I tried to find solutions but none seem to help. I have 5.0.18 virtualbox on Ubuntu 16.04

EDIT:
Now i am getting this error:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine VM-1.

Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-wlo1' (you might need to modprobe vboxnetflt to make it accessible) (VERR_SUPDRV_COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND).

Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and execute 'modprobe vboxdrv' as root (VERR_SUPDRV_COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

I am doing as the error says but the same error appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have encountered this.  You can move the file without errors if you use the VirtualBox **Virtual Media Manager**.  It's found under the **File** menu.  When you open it, you'll see a screen like this:

[image]

Find the file you want to move and right-click it.  Choose the **Release** option.  You will get an "are you sure" popup if the file is associated with a VM, that's OK. Just get it to disappear from the list by clicking the **Release** button on the box.

Now move your file, then go into the settings for your virtual machine and add the virtual hard drive back.  You shouldn't see this "already exists" error any more.

I do not know what to do about the network error.  You might want to ask a different question about that one, if after you move the file, you still get that.